# How to get Generic Inference using the Command Pattern in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, type-inference, typescript-generics, command-pattern

My use case is a Condition engine. Each JS object represents a type of condition that I must evaluate, or error if it is not supported.

The simplified code below works as in it executes and logs `true` in the console as needed. The problems are mostly about typing and inference:

1. `this.actions[name] = command;` triggers a typescript typing error because of the generics I use: `Type 'Command<D, Out>' is not assignable to type 'Command<CommandData, Out>'.`
2. The client doesn't get typings for the data object despite giving the Condition name we registered a couple of lines above.

[Directly see in the TypeScript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/PQKhCgAIUhhB7AtoghgOwCaQCIoC4pQjDjjDCQCqAzgKZYCWaetATmigDacCe4TLVgDMUAY1pwkqTLgKQA3uACQAbQDWtHgC5I1PKyYBzALo70fAL6lykAKIAPQR248ANJDwALCdRSIJAO4MXpAokAAGHP7hkAAOrPCxbHg8HvCQDBi0zAxCqQGeDKKeksjoWHjpolyc-MxsIuKQAHJ+9AhlMvhhtI7ZGNSl0hiyYYpKUbQ6egZohuBWZGBEQ+VEJOApSauYADwAkmiQvSyYgx3Do+4A8gCueAB8kAC8kAAUGN06h+4ARrfUHQXcoAIQBuzujwAlC8ngAFBKIBh0CH3B4Abmsy2gOywACVaIZkfo+NANlsJMDMASiTMeAcjid+ucpOUrpBIU9XgTRPBWBhdjMjO4qQKfhy0Q8sRAcaLIGDqCsALQSvCxe4ZQa-eDwTi0dCQIR8jzeXQoDSQeBCXQMRCxThFYKkmAqyHqvCQILcSC-CQGwzZNhFDJoPT6rBvI2sY6sBLRzzlB1zKHrUiiTgoagszoYBWox4KKCQYvq34O0ShUR4BjwUNA1nUwnE1j00XszkvBQWTFF4soDAC7DHPpnXHttFvSbTfTCyC8nP1nO7bA3NEw8ZKGz7SBoWj0NKQAESABEAAE8NQlQxDGg+bRj5BvKwJPAvGwgnQMh7EPB0IDSEom4UAAKjw2wAOSisuq6POBmo7q+oRZteHBlhIlQeGBEiQQ2Aptt0MEPOBAB0kDKEBkCgUkgxWnEKCsG0giDOBnwEHB5SQCx3Tsc+IbzrE+AMGhpHkTYVHYfhbHwbeHqZtQKEoGhB4Upx2AkaJFA4TmoxwciSHyTeil6sppq8qG+goAIlrWip4FqX8Gp2XBvK3JwWC+iGejoNW+D7kEIRhBguRCGw2QetQty-CptFmTMlnMJxkkoOpgHkV4yLEWI1a1tQKiTMYnbzsMmLFsWiylUhPBoBWvS0KI9y0JObTTrMhjuKxKCLpc3QwjoCJIMitD5k8igVRVz54Lc7AmhlWU1qGeVtMYHwETN1BQpiSiLEoAZ4K0-gAGKIqMK0EDo+3tLhoyQAAPqEaA8FCLVGLdO6uZwhaAbk7wAIQdbdd1-d0xGTDCE1TUcaDveR31vD96XUJlVbzblHUg0tYO0JN01Q9w5Hg9Np1hJmLRtBgSVQuj-jKFYiygDKMCwA6YUrAAjKR2C0EITC0IMwQ0QERyioMbzxIkgwANSPombApjiABMpE0sSbAmrQiCesEJRvvKAKpmQFCijoxR1WoxwAI63FwTo+ljAR7kceABOkQpzIqdSCI0EgAMoznMtjm0lw6nAMY7dJ9epCHgz1zMoBiGJ40e6H78yLLFHq+61AdG7iuyZ0Y2dXat2q6vqaBcpV1XvB1MLPCNcdYxDkBo5HHrPO3zfA-HicLNYhu4Toz4YLcTTFAwbnPkcRUcbV9XZaG91YCbohm7QlvWykoSGPFehq8OSRVvuABuXC3LQpACA0YgSLYR9sDwQdMqOQfjNPZxdWy3QqMYygn5wZ8AH4dAlz1OgXu4B052Dvi2HOUFb73ySn8HUoDy6dkzFVCsRMHLrVhJ9ZQkDegHxYBgAAaqfCQrw0Z-zPgDDwrAz74Jyh6MeE9sjC07GjN+AwAKQOfBFTgF40EBEsh6fqSI6CZW4G8ciLCMCT2FsRVAsQ3hvFkbXeugElCQMmJ2f4iNdoXSOkgE6ajyJKAJpDNokAAE+gBMRWeDUmr+HcGoyAfVESDWInw3Ud9IxcDoCmQCFhAkpmUFGd4vDeauQ9LRPh0ScEblhnEgRkAfod0IXVYhZD-60ECYBCxhp-Hny2gBAp+gz5KHAVucy3kGC+T3noxekBny0kEHvYWECmG2MGK8XcARcR5hAWXB4bwUx6MygON44R4EtnCO4GZD9cJjLsf2DAUz87+3XpwagczIAbMMIXHMoSbDAB+gAHUok+CQelbyYViC9K5hpjQ63+m8OgZksD0UMFCP4mZ9y1j3joyMDBWC7y+SmAh9g6r3HmrouxDiWBTIWbs1+uFASQBUORDcExmoRH2QHK22y5lmNbjocIilRDEs0d3JO5LfiUtcORCwjLALYqnHilOBL-FUsAqSiIrN5YAGYeXmOvInMlArhUsq2iyn+wTSAIvmsoYib40CqJyqXYinB4DfOVdUPAxR1Whk1WwOMUIgA)

**The Library Code**

The Bus must know nothing about Command names since these are added dynamically by the client. It must type the `execute` method's `data` argument based on the `name` argument (inferred via the `add` method used earlier on by the client).

```js
// Used internally
interface CommandData {
    [key: string]: any
}

// Externally, the same with a `name` property to identify which Command to call
interface NamedCommandData extends CommandData {
    name: string
}

type Command<In extends CommandData, Out> = (data: In, bus: CommandBus<Out>) => Promise<Out>;

type CommandRegistry<In extends CommandData, Out> = Record<string, Command<In, Out>>

class CommandBus<Out> {
    public actions: CommandRegistry<CommandData, Out> = {};

    add<D extends CommandData, Out>(name: string, command: Command<D, Out>) {
        // I need to use "@ts-ignore" here otherwise it moans:

        // Type 'Command<D, Out>' is not assignable to type 'Command<CommandData, Out>'. 
        // Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible. 
        // Type 'CommandData' is not assignable to type 'D'.
        // 'CommandData' is assignable to the constraint of type 'D', but 'D' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'CommandData'.
        
        this.actions[name] = command;
    }

    async execute(name: string, data: CommandData) : Promise<Out> {
        return this.actions[name](data, this);
    }

    getNameFromData(data: NamedCommandData | any): string | null {
        if (!data || !data.name) return null
        if (!this.actions[data.name]) return null
        return (data as NamedCommandData).name
    }
}
```

Overall Structure:

- `Command` - interface representng the handler of a specific command type; each receives its data and the bus (to be able to process children if there are any)

  - `EveryCommand` - received `EveryCommandData` so to take a boolean expected value and children Commands to evaluate
  - `StringEqualsCommand` - receives `StringEqualsCommandData` which are two strings (data.left and data.right)
- `CommandData` is a simple interface all concrete Commands' input data extend. `NamedCommandData` the public version with an additional `name: string` to identify the right handler (e.g. `name: "StringEquals"`).
- `CommandBus` is the entry point for clients. They can add their Commands as well as execute them.
- `CommandRegistry` is where Command names and handlers are stored for lookup and execution.

**The Client Code**

1. Defines its own Commands (props + handler)
2. Register them with the Bus
3. Execute

```js
// Command: check equality between two strings

interface StringEqCommandData extends CommandData {
    left: string
    right: string
}

const StringEqCommand: Command<StringEqCommandData, boolean> = async (data) => {
    return data.left === data.right
}

// Command: reduce children command executions and check equality against the expected value

interface EveryCommandData extends CommandData {
    commands: CommandData[]
    value: boolean
}

const EveryCommand: Command<EveryCommandData, boolean> = async (data, bus) => {
    
    const expectedValue = data.value
    const childrenCommands = data.commands

    const results = await Promise.all(
        childrenCommands.map((child) => {
            const name = bus.getNameFromData(child)
            return name ? bus.execute(name, child) : Promise.resolve(false)
        })
    )

    for (const result of results) {
        if (result !== expectedValue)
            return false
    }

    return true 
}

// Instantiate the bus and register the Commands
const bus = new CommandBus<boolean>()
bus.add(`Every`, EveryCommand)
bus.add(`StringEquals`, StringEqCommand)

// /!\ There is no typing here for the data (second arg), based on the name (first arg)
const execution = bus.execute(`Every`, {
    value: true,
    commands: [
        {
            name: `StringEquals`,
            left: `abc`,
            right: `abc`,
        },
        {
            name: `StringEquals`,
            left: `123`,
            right: `123`,
        },
    ]
})

execution
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: This is a tricky one because when you store the command in an object with the type `CommandRegistry<CommandData, Out>` you've lost the association between a specific command and it's specific data.  So your execute function cannot require that the data is the right type for the string name argument.  Is this something that you are still looking for help with?  I think I can *probably* do it if I make use of `asserts this is` typescript syntax, but no promises!

Comment: It becomes a lot easier if you pass in a command object rather than a string name, but then your `CommandBus` isn't doing much.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I tried to take your current code and fix the typescript issues, but this gets really messy really fast.  When you store your `actions` as a string-indexed record, you lose the association between specific key strings and their specific arguments.  If `actions` was a `readonly` property where an array of commands was passed into the constructor, we could make the class generic dependent on the actions object, and that would allow us to require that a `string` name must be a valid key of `this.actions` and that the corresponding `data` value matches the type for this key.

But you are instantiating the class with an empty object and adding actions one by one, which means that typescript needs to change what it knows about the class after each `add()`.  You make `add()` return something like `asserts this is this & {actions: [key in Name]: Command<D, Out> }`.  But this whole approach didn't work because your `Command` type takes `bus: CommandBus<Out>` as an argument and expects it to be generic dependent on `Out` only.

This is a "back to the drawing board" situation.  Trying to infer the required type for the data based on a string name is a mess, so we have to think what the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is and isn't designed to do.  The `Command` interface has a sole method `execute()` **which takes no arguments** because it encapsulates the information that it needs.  We need to make use of encapsulation here.

#### Higher-Order Functions

We don't need to use classes if we don't want to.  Let's define `Command<Out>` as a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Promise` which resolves to `Out`.

```
type Command<Out> = () => Promise<Out>
```

But a string comparison does require some data, so we use a higher-order function which takes the data and returns a function with the `Command<boolean>` signature.

```
interface StringEqCommandData {
    left: string
    right: string
}

const createStringEquals = ({left, right}: StringEqCommandData): Command<boolean> => 
async () => {
    return left === right
}
```

(probably I would make this two arguments `left` and `right` rather than a keyed object)

We can do the same with the "every" command.  In this case our arguments include other `Command<boolean>` functions.

```
interface EveryCommandData {
    commands: Command<boolean>[]
    expectedValue?: boolean
}

const createEveryCommand = ({commands, expectedValue = true}: EveryCommandData): Command<boolean> => 
async () => {
    const results = await Promise.all(commands.map( c => c() ) );
    return results.every( r => r === expectedValue );
}
```

We don't need `CommandBus` at all since we can create a function and call it ourselves.

```
const execution = createEveryCommand({
    commands: [
        createStringEquals({
            left: `abc`,
            right: `abc`,
        }),
        createStringEquals({
            left: `123`,
            right: `123`,
        }),
    ]
})();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/PTAEENQYQewWzuAdgE1ASwM4VAMwK5IDGALujEqAO4AW6RNoApseAA6b4A24JT26EthhVKKXpGRoiyUACMmoGVy5M0VQYyQwIAJwDm%20OCyGgAUGZIBPNotgIpAHgDy%20EgD5QAXlAAKAJTengAKuvBYTC5u7hYg0PCIqABcSjRMRADWzACO%20OBcglbyTCRUTCygpTqYJLroSPqYFvV8urjgRIoAyrX1%20gCi2faJKAAiEqAA3mYAkKq4JCk1dQ2zdfo0i6DLfWYAvhZEFDVKuky8TD0rA7n52D6%20k-MkADSg65t7KVd9g8NS4xI4H8KX%20qEcchgMFUyE8Xk8ZnAmCsxD8gXhUzWJXwukoz28Xh8HxI%201iYDBKBSZxQ%20E6qXQXBQZ0oRwcqGYAA90m5yEhsFJUukskxbgVrBB9OB6icSGlObZSGpQAA3fL4JjNJCtdp0-rKpi6KwUwGQaYzVkjTCghJOSHQ85IdwAbQAurMmByFXwUAA1NVMAD8KTtMKQpLMRz5JFO5z4eoNRpt7IekwtUkwbw9XrUfq46u8lV06q%20oHjhuNEhB8TZKAhUNDcIRSJRRDRQUx5uO0bOnC4ph84CoUujoXCmCYADp8lxfGnUJgJ4g2L4lO2iAFQIF-ABuLEkHGUHvcIQTpj6w0r3Ttq%20EnxZ9Le3P5nfhyMnD3csgUAtEM4XMuJjWjyzHOKBWqATqzOaf58D8DSDHkXCYMBMyoc8KQAAbgHIRAYS8UEzMSmHYbh%20GoXs-hkdBsaXL08GishZpoUwCyYQAjAATAAzHhBFEaAGGcTxVEUWRboUQEu5mB%20RA8hQswTrKLCzsc9oTlwMD6P4CkyCQDAqXyakGmEuj%20EAA)

#### Classes

We can also use a traditional class-based approach, where we define `Command<Out>` as an object with a method `execute()` which takes no arguments and returns a `Promise` that resolves to `Out`.

```
interface Command<Out> {
    execute(): Promise<Out>;
}
```

We can create classes that take their data in the constructor and are created by calling `new`.

```
class StringEquals implements Command<boolean> {
    private readonly _data: StringEqCommandData;

    constructor(data: StringEqCommandData) {
        this._data = data;
    }

    public async execute() {
        return this._data.left === this._data.right;
    }
}

const myCommand = new StringEquals({left: "abc", right: "abc"});
myCommand.execute();
```

Your `every` case could take an array of commands in the constructor or it could add them one by one with an `add()` method like in your `CommandBus`.  It can store the specific command which caused it to fail.  Maybe in addition to `execute()` we want to require our commands to have a `name` property.

Blending the two approaches, we can also use a factory function to create an object with an `execute()` function.

```
const createStringEquals = (data: StringEqCommandData): Command<boolean> => {
    return {
        execute() {
            return Promise.resolve(data.left === data.right);
        } 
    }
}
```